# ios5 - store kit - Getting expiry date for non-renewable subscription

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

In my application, I'm using auto renewable subscription. But apple rejected the app saying that, i've to use non-renewable subscription. I changed the corresponding things in itunes connect. but the problem is that how can I get the expiry date of the non-renewable subscription after making a purchase. do I have to do it manually by adding the number of days to current date and calculate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to monitor it manually with in the code.

Comment: do u knowImplementing Non -Renewable subscriptions Using mkstorekit are they same as consumable products(in implementation)?

Comment: or can we have the same approach as a nonconsumable product,ie purchase it then calculate the expdate and store it in our server and check the exp date and show the purchase button again is it right?

Comment: No you cannot handle it similar. When you subscribe a product, you will get the receipt which has some additional parameters to track back the purchases. This has to be handled on the server. You need to generate a secret key kind of thing on the server when registering the products to the app in itunesconnect.apple.com

Comment: i am using mkstorekit,in that i am adding this as subscriptions,and when the purchase occurs i am calling a webservice and giving the purchase date and all details to that, there it will store it on ur details that we have already then calculating an exp status,and returning it and according to that i am showing the view is it right

Comment: how are you calculating the "expiry" date?

Comment: with the purchase date i am adding the desired amount of time and calculating an exp staus in my server php code and returning this to my code.Now i am associating the subscription with my app user,so that he can use it anywhere in the world from any device, i have doubt that is it ok.(ie they r actually meant the itunes user)?can u reply me immedietly?R u in chat?because i am in ome urgency

Comment: sorry i don't have continuous internet access. i doubt whether apple will accept it do you have to check with apple server to verify whether the subscription is purchased or not. are you providing any "restore" button in the app or not?

Comment: Ya i am checking with apple server to verify whether the subscription is purchased or not.no i dnt provide any restore button?what is the need for that?

Comment: If user has purchased a subscription today (think it is valid for 1 month). He will delete the app tomorrow or will change his iPhone. Then install the app again or on new phone. You have to provide "restore" button so that he don't have to purchase subscription again. Got my point?

Comment: if he login to my app with the same username he will easily get it.because i am associating it with the username in my own server.any way my app is rejected for a reason i am forcing the user to register

Comment: but my app is rejected for a reason my registration is not optional

Comment: are u creating the registration screen at the start of the app or in the middle? it cannot be in the middle.